# values.map is not a function reactjs

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

i am fetchin details from database wanted to display that into the table, but for initial purpose i wanted to just display on browser without table and stuff.. am getting values.map is not a function but i could the see values printed in console

here iam using function component

```
export default function SimpleTable() {
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
```

here is the fetch function

```
async function handleTable(){
const res = await fetch("http://localhost:4000/productslist")
const data = await res.json()
setValues(data.data)
console.log(data.data)
}
```

calling the fetch function on useEffect

```
useEffect(()=>{
handleTable()
},[])
```

Rendering the values into browser

```
return (
<div>

{console.log(values)}
{values.map(v => {
return  <h4 key={v.idaddproducts}>{v.productName}{v.productId}{v.productBrand}</h4>})}
</div>
);
}
```

here is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: values.map is not a function
```

Comment: you're setting values initial value as an `{}` instead set it to `[]`

Comment: for your initial `values` is a object . `Array.map` is a valid prototype .so change the initial `values` to array `const [values, setValues] = useState([])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial state of your values is an empty object

From

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
```

Update to

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
```

Since Object doesn't have a method called `.map`

Also in your code since its a async call you can check based on a state whether data has load or not a simple thing you can add is a ternary check

```
{values.length && values.map(v => {
return  <h4 key={v.idaddproducts}>{v.productName}{v.productId}{v.productBrand}</h4>})}
</div>
);
```

so once the array has a length greater than zero only it will execute the map function

Working [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59607803-so-async-data-loading-useeffect-53jhd) With Sample Example

Comment: Can you help me in adding loading state also ?

Comment: can you recommend any course or links ? regard fullstack reactjs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205413/discussion-between-dileep-thomas-and-logesh-p).

Answer (score 1):

Define your state as an array

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
```

Code

```
{values && values.map(v => {
  return  <h4 key={v.idaddproducts}>
           {v.productName}{v.productId}{v.productBrand} 
          </h4>
  })
 }
```

Comment: You need to add values.length as the ternary check since empty array is true value

Comment: Worked fine.. with the changes you gave.. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You set a value `{}` instead of `[]`.
Update

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
```

to

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
```

Comment: This change alone won't work.. i tried it several times

Comment: It may because of values should be null or undefined from the api response.